# Why does my counter of "posts edited" not increase?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

I have my account on Stack Overflow, usually edit posts occasionally and noticed that my counter increased for each post he accepted my edit.

Recently I have noticed that my counter does not increase by more posts you edit. This happened since I got 2K reputation.

**My question:**

Is there a way to continue editing posts normally and increase my counter to get badges related to posting edits?

Comment: Just to clarify... you don't get **rep** for [edits after hitting 2K](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) but you definitely should still get credit for them as it relates to badges.

Comment: @Catija typically I earned 2 for each post but now do not give me anything

Comment: ... Like I said... you don't get rep (reputation points) for edits after you hit 2K reputation.

Comment: @Catija ok, I understand that not get rep, but what about post edit counter?

Comment: [This number](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4220815/cmedina?tab=activity&sort=revisions) (currently 217 or 171 depending on which version you look at) **should** continue to increase as you submit edits... just look at it whenever you submit an edit and you should see that it changes... assuming you're editing someone else's post and not your own.

Comment: As @Cat said, your rep shouldn't increase but that number should. Also give it some time; this stuff is cached and you won't see it change as soon as you submitted an edit.

Comment: OK, thks a lot!

Comment: @Catija you will still get +2 rep for tag wikis and excerpts, however, until you hit 20k.

Comment: @JAL actually, you get rep for any suggested edit, so long as it's a suggested edit, and the total is below 1k rep.